# Could you use ASICBOOST on Bitcoin Cash?

Tags: mining-hardware, bitcoin-cash, asicboost

Can you use ASICBOOST on the Bitcoin Cash blockchain or would it not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ASICBoost works on the Bitcoin Cash blockchain because the block header format of Bitcoin Cash blocks are the same as the block header format of Bitcoin blocks. ASICBoost operates on the block headers. Furthermore, both overt and covert ASICBoost work on Bitcoin Cash.